# Can SQL views be saved like indexes?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a one to many relationship between the two entities, Patient and Appointment. Where a Patient might have one or more appointments. And in many cases, I need to get the first appointment of eah patient, or the last appointment of each patient..

If I do this as a nested query, the server has to run a sub query for each and every patient. And it takes too much excecution time.

If I create a view as the following:

```
CREATE VIEW vwPatientFirstAppointment AS
SELECT id,
    (
        SELECT id 
        FROM Appointment 
        WHERE Appointment.PatientId = Patient.id
        ORDER BY Appointment.starttime
        LIMIT 1
    ) FirstAppointmentId
FROM Patient
```

This wouldn't help much because as far as I know, the query inside the view will be re-executed everytime the view is used. So is there a way the server can save the results of such a view and only re-evaluate it when the data changes?

Comment: You may want to look into materialised view.

Comment: Yeah that sounds pretty much like what I'm looking for! I'll check it out! Thank you!

Comment: `the server has to run a sub query for each and every patien` No it won't. Check the querypan. BTW: your `limit=1` syntax is wrong, and there is `row_number() over(..)`, And you don't need the scalar subquery.

Comment: Ok I fixed the syntax error. Can you please post a detailed answer. I'm not sure what you're trying to suggest

Comment: Add to the question how you **use** this view in another *(main)* query, and the resulting query plan. (BTW: there is now such thing as a *nested query*)